# Is it a good practice to use object literals and bind all methods using lodash?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I used to create my services and utils like that:

```
const StudentsService = Object.freeze({f1(a){this.f2(a)},f2(b){}});
```

And the further usage is like:

```
const students = StudentsService.f1(respFromApi);
```

But as it turned out, I can run into some issues using keyword `this` with current approach. For example:

```
f3().then(StudentsService.f1);
```

And the function can refer to StudentsService context no more, and I got undefined. I know that my problem could be fixed with bind/apply/call. Also I can do something like that

```
f3().then(data => StudentsService.f1(data))
```

And the context won't be lost.
But I have a feeling that I'm doing something wrong. I'm afraid to forget add a fix at one moment and my app will crash.

So since I'm using **lodash** I'm just wondering to add _.bindAll and everything will be looking like

```
const StudentsService = Object.freeze(_.bindAll({f1(a){this.f2(a)},f2(b){}}));
```

What is the best solution or practice to avoid this issue or resolve it most efficient way and with minimal efforts. Big thanks!

Comment: There are alternatives, like using closures with private variables. What is "best practice" is a matter of opinion. I would stick with embracing `this` and avoid passing function references as callback arguments, unless they are `this`-less.

Comment: @trincot Yes, I also thought about using closures. But for me it is all like bad-smell code. There's another alternative to use a class with only static methods, though it's a little bit weird in my opinion. Probably, I should remove my objects and etc. and just stick with plain functions without any classes/objects.

Comment: A class with only static methods (where I assume you would pass the object to act on as argument) is indeed another alternative where you walk away from OOP. That is not my preference, but again, all this is a matter of personal opinion. Some proponents have very strong convictions, but all options have both strengths and weaknesses. Using static methods with object argument is like using `.call()` or `.apply()` on object methods, which again is an option.

Comment: @trincot Thanks for your response! Could you please clarify what do you mean by an "object argument" ?
I didn't quite catch why you paid attention for this moment indeed. Is there any difference what type of arg to pass to a static method?

Comment: Well, when you call a static method, you would need to pass it some context, unless you only have singleton objects. But in general you would have several objects of the same kind, and would want to have a set of methods that can be called on any one of these objects. So then you need to somehow ensure the method knows on which of these objects to act. If on the other hand you only have singletons, then indeed the whole OOP thing is overkill, and you could just do with a set of static functions or global functions.